# Previously saved Product ids should not display again in form

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

magento site : www.1234.com

We have lot of Designers in site (Seller/ Vendor). we assigned each product to one Designer with help of attribute `Designer ID` as below image under `Catalog > Manage Products` section

[image]

We are using below code in **www.1234.com/php/site6/padistatus.php** to display form & saving form values in `order_details`  column. [ custom database ]

[image]

here once we select **Designer** from dropdown, than related **Order numbers** of that designer will display, after selecting `order number` , it will display related **Products Ids** of that Order Number.

here for "Product ids" , we are saving values in "dproduct_id" column.

[image]

what we need is **Previously selected & saved Product Ids should not display again** in dropdown

example : here we already saved **15517** product Id in Database, so it should not display again in form. only **15515** product Id should display in dropdown.

full code : http://pastebin.com/PT6A0wrA

**Edit**

With help of below code , Previously saved product ids are not displaying **per designer** but i need solution for Previously saved product ids should not display for all designers.

assume In one order [ **order id : 100000136** ] 
, 2 designers products will be sold [ ex : **sudeep's product id : 15442 & Darshan product id : 152**] , so that when we select Darshan in dropdown, only Darshan's product id 152 should display, but now product id 152 is  displaying for both Sudeep & Darshan. same happening for Another product id also.

**updated code :**

```
 <table>
      <tr><td> Designer  </td><td>

          <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name="designer_id" id="designer_id" >
            <option value="">Select Designer</option>
                  <?php 
                       while($data = $stmt->fetch())  
                        { 
                           if($data['type']=="admin")continue;
                  ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['userID'];?>">
                  <?php 
                     echo $data['name'];
                  ?>
            </option>
                  <?php } ?>
          </select>

     </td><td><p id="error_para1" ></p></td></tr> 


      <tr><td>Order Number: </td><td>


        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id" class="designerorder_id" onchange='getProductDetail(this.value)'>
            <option value="">Select Order</option>
          </select>
          </div>

        </td><td><p id="error_para2" ></p></td></tr> 




      <tr><td>Product</td><td>


        <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_id" id="dproduct_id" >
          <select id="mySelect" >
            <option>Select Products</option>
          </select>

        </div>


       </td><td><p id="error_para3" ></p></td> </tr>
```

**Designerpaidstatus.php**

```
$htmltext='';   
//$htmltext.="<select id='designerpaidstatus.php' name='designerorder_id' onchange='getProductDetail(this.value)' class='selectvalue'><option value=''>Select Order</option>";
$htmltext.="<option value=''>Select Order</option>";
$data=array();

foreach ($order as $orderData)  
{

$sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";
$sqlq=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlq1);

while($rdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq))
{
$data[]=$rdata['dproduct_id'];

}


$orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];
$oitem=explode(',',$orderitems);
$finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
$result=array_diff($oitem,$data);
$result1=implode(',',$result);

if(count($result)>1){  

$htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$result1.'" name="'.$result1.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>';

} }

$htmltext=$htmltext."</select>";
echo $htmltext;
exit;
```

**script**

```
function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;    
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              //document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;
              $(".designerorder_id").html(result);

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }

    function getProductDetail(e)
      {    
        var productId = $(".designerorder_id option:selected").attr("class");  //$('option:selected', this).attr('class'); 

        var finalstrig=productId.split(",");

        var select='';
        select+='<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">';

        for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
        {
          if(finalstrig[i]!=0)
          {
            select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
          }
        }
        select +='</select>';   
        document.getElementById('productnumbers').innerHTML =select;
        (function($) {
        $(function() {
            $('.test').fSelect();
        });
    })(jQuery);

      }

    $(function(){
      $("#button_reset").click(function() { 
        $("#productnumbers").html('<select id="mySelect"><option>Select Products</option></select>');
      });
    });
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2**

what below query do is

**1.it first execute a like query with designer id and fetches all the orders  :**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));
```

**2. Iterates through the order and fetches all the product ids....**

```
$sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";
```

**so when i execute any of below queries, there will be a common row and all the product id from that row will appear for all these designers.**

when i ran below query in magento database, i got result as below image.

```
select * from sales_flat_order where designer_id like '%4%'; 
select * from sales_flat_order where designer_id like '%5%'; 
select * from sales_flat_order where designer_id like '%8%'; 
select * from sales_flat_order where designer_id like '%9%';
```

[image]

Comment: What is the logic to already saved product_id find in your database?

Comment: I second @DhirenVasoya question. Without the code that retrieves the product id no one can help you here

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism please check script  `function getProductDetail(e)` .....

Comment: But how are those values retrieved from the database ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism please check `Edit` part in question, we are using only those code i posted in question.....

Comment: @Baby in Magento Well come back :)

Comment: @Abdul thanks, can you please help me, i am really struggling for this from last one month.....

Comment: can you please explain your issues?

Comment: @Abdul We have lot of `Designers` in site `(Seller/ Vendor)`. we assigned each product to one Designer with help of attribute `Designer ID` as this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exyot.png under `Catalog > Manage Products` section

Comment: okay but what is issue?

Comment: @Abdul  so when customer order , that contains many products [ product may be of `designer1 , designer 2....etc until designer n`  now in `dropdown` when we select `designer` only that `designer order id & product id` should display, but now those `product ids` are displaying for other designers also [ means its displaying for those designers who are also there in that order`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51075/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-abdul).

Comment: There is a ajax call at the time of order id selection. Can you please share that file code to solve this issue.

Comment: @AshishJagnani paidstatus page full code : http://pastebin.com/rVuGMEK6 
designerpaidstatus.php full code : http://pastebin.com/6vNtGTge

Comment: @AshishJagnani also you can see in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/paidstatus.php) , enmail : kidsdial1@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial1

Comment: In which table and column you are saving these product ids which we have to filter from multi dropdown ?

Comment: @AshishJagnani `order_details` table , column is `dproduct_id` for saving product ids & `designerorder_id` column name for saving "order ids`.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'class.user.php';

$deliverydDate=date('Y-m-d');
$user_homes = new USER();
$id=$_GET['designer_id'];

require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));

$conVar=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbName);

    $htmltext='<select>';  
$htmltext.="<option value=''>Select Order</option>";



foreach ($order as $orderData) 
{

/* for order hide */

    $data=array();
    $sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";
    $sqlq=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlq1);

    while($rdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq))
    {
        $data[]=$rdata['dproduct_id'];

    }
    $orderitems=$orderData->getData('dproduct_id');
    $oitem=explode(',',$orderitems);
    $finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
    $result=array_diff($oitem,$data);
    $result1=implode(',',$result);
    //$result1 = explode(',',$orderitems);
    //$result1 = $sqlq1;
    if(count($result)>1){  
        $result2=array();
        foreach($result as $product)
        {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
            $_productDesignerId = $_product->getDesignerId();
            if(trim($_productDesignerId) == trim($id))
            {
                $result2[] = trim($product);
            }
        }
        $result2=implode(',',$result2);

        $htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$result2.'" name="'.$result2.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>';
    } 
/* for order hide end */
/* for designer hide */
/* for designer end */

}

    $htmltext=$htmltext."</select>";
    echo $htmltext;exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: updated code, still same result.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, Please check my updated answer. Also let me know if you have any field in magento order table like "dproduct_id" ?

Comment: please check `Edit2` part in question.....

Comment: Updated code, sorry still same result.....

Comment: updated code, please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/paidstatus.php) , email : kidsdial1@gmail.com  , pw : kidsdial1 , [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/paidstatus.php) , now i can not able to sleect values from `order number dropdown`

Comment: @BabyinMagento, Link will not work in my system. Let me know the output. Output may be in firebug.

Comment: okay, i wil try to get output and inform you......

Comment: please join here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/51224/magento?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

You can do this things to,

1. Before showing product value in dropdown, Call one Ajax Requestion
2. In Ajax Request pass that Product Id
3. Now on that ajax url, in php code check that product_id is show or not in dropdown
4. Based on Ajax request result can add that value in dropdown or not.

   ```
   function getProductDetail(e)
     {    
       var productId = $("#dproductselect option:selected").attr("class");  
       var finalstrig=productId.split(",");

       var select='';
       select+='<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">';

       for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
       {
          //CREATE ONE AJAX CALL TO CHECK IS THIS PRODUCT ID SHOW IN DROPDOWN OR NOT 
          var returnresult = 0;
          var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/productdropdown.php?p_id="+finalstrig[i]; 
          var request = jQuery.ajax( {
               url: url ,
               type: 'POST',                      
           } );

           request.done( function (result)
           {  
              returnresult = 1;

           });
           request.fail( function ( error )
           {
               console.dir(error);             
           } );

         if(finalstrig[i]!=0 && returnresult)
         {
           select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
         }
       }
       select +='</select>';   
       document.getElementById('productnumbers').innerHTML =select;
       (function($) {
       $(function() {
           $('.test').fSelect();
       });
   })(jQuery);

     }
   ```

Comment: if you update an answer with `ajax request` , that will be really helpfull.....

Comment: create file  productdropdown.php and do the code to check where this id display or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
dont add any file.. In your designerpaidstatus.php file check if id already exist or not. if exist then compare values of your both tables.... 


 $sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";
$sqlq=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlq1);

while($rdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq))
{
$data[]=$rdata['dproduct_id'];

}

$orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $oitem=explode(',',$orderitems);
            $finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
$result=array_diff($oitem,$data);
$result1=implode(',',$result);

            if(count($result)>1){  

$htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$result1.'" name="'.$result1.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>';
```

Comment: please check `Edit2` part in question.....

Answer (score 1):

@NishantSaini code i doubt on below line

```
$orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];
```

above line should be

```
$orderitems=$orderData->getDproductId();  //because its part of order collection
```

In the line no 15 change below line

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));
```

TO

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));
```

Comment: if this not solve your concern provide me all code file

Comment: I changed code, but still same result , you can see full code under `Edit` part in question, also here : paidstatus : http://pastebin.com/cm7icaBi , designerpaidstatus.php : http://pastebin.com/zvk9mBQP

Comment: @BabyinMagento check updated line I have written wrong spelling in variable

Comment: updated code, sorry still same issue is there......

Comment: @BabyinMagento check updated answer

Comment: updated code, now in 2nd field `order number` , no dropdown values  [ `order numbers` ] are displaying after we select designer.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento syntax error , updated my code check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51158/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: please check `Edit2` part in question.....

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

in file `update_paidstatus.php` change the code like

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST!="" && !empty($_POST)){ // checking if form submision is occured or not.

    $sucessFlag=true;
    $productIds=explode(",",$_POST['dproduct_id']);

    $oDate = new DateTime($_POST['dueDate']);
    $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");   
    if(isset($conVar) && !empty($conVar) && $conVar!="")
    {
       for ($i=0; $i< count($productIds); $i++) {   

         $sqlQueryToUpdate="INSERT INTO order_details ( designer_id,designerorder_id,dproduct_id,dpaid_status,delivery_status,due_date) VALUES('".$_POST['designer_id']."','".$_POST['designerorder_id']."','".$productIds[$i]."','".$_POST['PaidStatus']."','".$_POST['PaidStatus']."','".$sDate."')";

            $sucessFlag=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlQueryToUpdate);
                if($sucessFlag==TRUE)
                    {
                       echo "UPDATE SUCESSFULLY";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo " not done.";
                    }           
         }
        header('Location: '.$newURL);  
    }
}
```